# x11vnc quits when I try to connect

Tags: xorg, vnc, x11-forwarding

I'm starting it like this:

```
x11vnc -display :0 -usepw -listen 127.0.0.1
```

Then when I connect from my computer, this happens:

```
8/08/2019 00:31:43 Got connection from client 127.0.0.1
28/08/2019 00:31:43   other clients:
28/08/2019 00:31:44 Normal socket connection
28/08/2019 00:31:44 check_access: checking against full string "127.0.0.1"
28/08/2019 00:31:44 check_access: client 127.0.0.1 fullmatch matches host 127.0.0.1
28/08/2019 00:31:44 Disabled X server key autorepeat.
28/08/2019 00:31:44   to force back on run: 'xset r on' (3 times)
28/08/2019 00:31:44 incr accepted_client=1 for 127.0.0.1:34256  sock=11
28/08/2019 00:31:44 Client Protocol Version 3.8
28/08/2019 00:31:44 Protocol version sent 3.8, using 3.8
28/08/2019 00:31:44 rfbProcessClientSecurityType: executing handler for type 2
28/08/2019 00:31:44 Pixel format for client 127.0.0.1:
28/08/2019 00:31:44   8 bpp, depth 8
28/08/2019 00:31:44   true colour: max r 7 g 7 b 3, shift r 0 g 3 b 6
28/08/2019 00:31:44 rfbProcessClientNormalMessage: ignoring unsupported encoding type ultraZip
28/08/2019 00:31:44 Using compression level 9 for client 127.0.0.1
28/08/2019 00:31:44 Using image quality level 0 for client 127.0.0.1
28/08/2019 00:31:44 Using JPEG subsampling 1, Q15 for client 127.0.0.1
28/08/2019 00:31:44 Enabling X-style cursor updates for client 127.0.0.1
28/08/2019 00:31:44 Enabling full-color cursor updates for client 127.0.0.1
28/08/2019 00:31:44 Enabling cursor position updates for client 127.0.0.1
28/08/2019 00:31:44 Enabling KeyboardLedState protocol extension for client 127.0.0.1
28/08/2019 00:31:44 Enabling NewFBSize protocol extension for client 127.0.0.1
28/08/2019 00:31:44 Enabling LastRect protocol extension for client 127.0.0.1
28/08/2019 00:31:44 Enabling SupportedMessages protocol extension for client 127.0.0.1
28/08/2019 00:31:44 Enabling SupportedEncodings protocol extension for client 127.0.0.1
28/08/2019 00:31:44 Enabling ServerIdentity protocol extension for client 127.0.0.1
28/08/2019 00:31:44 Using tight encoding for client 127.0.0.1
28/08/2019 00:31:44 client_count: 0
28/08/2019 00:31:44 Restored X server key autorepeat to: 1
28/08/2019 00:31:44 viewer exited.
28/08/2019 00:31:44 deleted 60 tile_row polling images.
```

As you see, it exits without any errors

Comment: Are you connecting over an SSH tunnel - or are you trying to start the VNC viewer on the same physical display that you are running the server on?

Comment: @steeldriver I'm using an ssh tunnel